# Sequelize equal to day

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm doing a calendar selection with a specific day, I'm passing in the query param and want to return results just for that day. Anyway to do this without a raw query?

```
if (query.hasOwnProperty('today') && query.today.length > 0) {
  today = query.today.replace(/%20/g, " ");

  // check for calendar selection to only show that days tasks
  if (query.hasOwnProperty('calendarSelect') && query.calendarSelect === 'true') {
    where.dueDate = {
      $eq: moment(today).toDate()
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you've posted?

Comment: It doesn't return any items.